# How can i use Relative or Environment variable in Batch command

Tags: command-line, command-prompt, soapui

I am running below command to run Soapui Test suite and it is working fine

```
testrunner.bat -s"TestSuite4" "D:\Invesco\JP Groovy Code\ExploreGroovy.xml"
```

I ahve also used with below command and it is working fine as well

```
testrunner.bat -s"TestSuite4" "%USERPROFILE%\ExploreGroovy.xml"
```

Now I have added one Envrionment variable 'EnvP' and its value id 'D:\Invesco' and tried with following command but it is not working.

```
testrunner.bat -s"TestSuite4" "%EnvP%\ExploreGroovy.xml"
```

Can some one help me in this. I don't want to give hard coded path of any drive. Please suggest if anyone has any other solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

- the process starting `testrunner.bat` (probably `explorer.exe`?) must
  know about the new variable. have you tried logging out and in again
  after setting it?
- if it is `cmd`, try finding the variable with `set | find "EnvP"`. If it is not there, you need to start a new `cmd` session.

Answer (score 0):

Use these commands and you should see why it fails:

```
@echo "%EnvP%"
@if not exist "%EnvP%\ExploreGroovy.xml" @echo Ouch!
@pause
testrunner.bat -s"TestSuite4" "%EnvP%\ExploreGroovy.xml"
@pause
```

Answer (score 0):

For all my SoapUI projects I have multiple .bat scripts in the **same location** as the project.xml file to run different sets of test suites, and all of it goes into your source repository.

```
IF NOT DEFINED SOAPUI_ROOT SET SOAPUI_ROOT=%ProgramFiles%\SmartBear\soapUI-Pro-4.6.4

REM make certain we are where we _think_ we are
CD %~dp0

REM cleanup previous results
DEL /f /q *.log*
RMDIR /s /q results

REM run the tests
CALL "%SOAPUI_ROOT%\bin\testrunner.bat" -s"Smoke TestSuite" -fresults My-soapui-project.xml

REM determine if there are failures
IF errorlevel 0 (
    ECHO All tests passed.
    PAUSE
    EXIT 0
) ELSE (
    ECHO There are failures!
    PAUSE
    EXIT 100
)
```